# JSON, invalid label, issue consuming JSON

Tags: json

I have an issue with my JSON. We area getting it from a SOAP service I believe. I am using jQuery AJAX to try to consume the JSON.  We are using the Asp.NET solution so I know about the "d" security feature and have in my dataFilter a way to try to get around that. I am getting the JSON back in Firebug but not to my local machine. The Service is on a domain separate from my local machine. I know about the cross domain policy issue but seems to be consuming the JSON in Firebug when I put the dataType as "jsonp" in the jQuery AJAX call.
If I set my dataType as "json" I get nothing back in Firebug.

The thing is my JSON has "\" slashes in it. I guess that is why Firebug is giving me an "invalid label" error. But I am not sure of that.

1. How can I filter out the "\" without doing the server side code again.
2. How can I just get the JSON back and alert on my page.

**My jQuery Ajax call is below.**

`$(document).ready(function () {`

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
         url: "http://www.myexternaldomain.com/jservice/myservice.svc/CurrentJsonDataFullWeatherPanel",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "jsonp",
       dataFilter: function(data) {
// This boils the response string down 
//  into a proper JavaScript Object().
            var msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
              return msg.d;
            else
              return msg;
          },
        success: function(msg) {
            // This will now output the same thing 
            //  across any current version of .NET.
            alert(msg);
          },
        error: function (result) {
                    alert('Failed:  ' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
    });

});
```

**My JSON output in Firebug shows like this.**
{"d":"[{\"AirTemperature\":\"57.3\",\"BarometricPressure\":\"30.08\",\"CurrentRainRate\":\"\",\"DewPointTemperature\":\"30.7\",\"HeatIndex\":\"57.3\",\"HourlyRainAmount\":\"0.00\",\"LocalObservationTime\":\"10/14/2011 11:16:07 AM\",\"MonthlyRainAmount\":\"\",\"RelativeHumidity\":\"36\",\"SnowDepth\":\"0.0\",\"SolarRadiation\":\"\",\"SunRise\":\"7:09 AM\",\"SunSet\":\"6:22 PM\",\"TodayRainAmount\":\"0.00\",\"Visibility\":\"6561\",\"WindChill\":\"57.3\",\"WindDirection\":\"2\",\"WindGust\":\"11.4\",\"WindGustDirection\":\"92\",\"WindSpeed\":\"4.9\",\"YearlyRainAmount\":\"22.24\",\"StationTime\":\"10/14/2011 11:15:24 AM\"}]"}

Any suggestions?
Do I need to use a different way than jQuery to consume my JSON?

I should add that my fail alert is sending back 200 success but hitting the error.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `eval('(' + data + ')');` with `$.parseJSON(data)`

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Just did that. Still same issue.